# Visual Studio Code - Dialogs open in Background

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the Powershell extension for Visual Studio Code and when I try and run cmdlets which bring up a form dialog (e.g.  Running connect-AzureAD ) these will open in background behind the VS Code window and cannot be seen.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Like when you run the file from VS Code, the PowerShell window appears behind the VS Code window?

Comment: no.  When I run Connect-AzureAD It will bring up a forms dialog to enter username/password for AAD sign in.  This dialog is hidden behind the main VSCode screen.

Comment: still have this problem, V.1.71.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It appears there are two bugs here, Windows: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42356 and Linux: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146422

Answer (score 1):

Try the following workaround i found on the issue page https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146422#issuecomment-1177157781.
Before opening Visual Studio Code, type the following on your terminal

`GTK_USE_PORTAL=0`

Tested on Fedora 37, Xorg